# Create html element with id consisting of string and integer

Tags: html, model-view-controller

How can i create a button with the id consisting of a string for example "Button" and the id in mvc

It is like this currently but i want to add the string "btn" infront of the id.

```
<button id="@Uid">
```

i tried

```
<button id="'btn'+@uid">
```

Btn is a string and uid is an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code

```
<button id="@("btn"+uid)">
```